# How to map an RDD of case class to LabeledPoint(label, feature vector)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to map an RDD of case class to LabeledPoint(label, feature vector).

This is the RDD of case class Exam(x : Double, y: Double) :

Ds(1.0,6.0)

Ds(2.0,8.0)

Ds(3.0,10.0)

Ds(3.0,10.0)

ds(4.0,12.0)

Ds(5.0,14.0)

Tried doing this -

```
     val parsedData = aRDD.map(row =>
     new LabeledPoint(
     row._1,
     Vectors.dense(row._2))
```

Getting error "value _1 is not a member of main.scala.spark.Q1Partb.Q1.Exam" at row._1 and row._2

and this -

```
          val parsedData = aRDD.map{line => 
          val Array(rawLabel, rawfeatures) = line.split(',')
          val features = rawfeatures) .split(' ').map(_.toDouble)
          LabeledPoint(rawLabel.toDouble, Vectors.dense(features))}
```

Getting error  "recursive value x$4 needs type" for rawLabel and "value split is not a member of main.scala.spark.Q1Partb.Q1.ds" for line.split(',')

Answer (score 1):

If you have an RDD[Exam] you should be able to write

```
val parsedData = aRDD.map(exam => LabeledPoint(exam.x, Vectors.dense(exam.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because my variable name was taken by a function.

So 
`private val Seq(transaction, transaction2) = insertTx(...`

became

`private val Seq(transaction1, transaction2) = insertTx(...`

with transaction being the culprit.